# How do I check my PC specs on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS?

Tags: ram, cpu

I do not know how to check the PC specs on Ubuntu.
Is there a specific command for this?
Or do I search it in the menu?

Tell me if I need to provide extra info.

Comment: I tend to like `sudo lshw` (ie.  list hardware... where `sudo` just elevates privileges to ensure it works); piped through a pager etc. as appropriate...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Go to Settings → *About*. You get some info there.

Else commands like `lshw` give you a complete list.

Answer (score 7):

You can also use neofetch. First install it:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install neofetch
```

To use it type

```
neofetch
```

and you will get something like this:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I usually use the commands `cat /proc/cpuinfo` (to get detailed information about the cpu including clock speeds etc.) and `lspci` (to get all devices connected to the pci buses such as graphics cards etc.), and of course these are specifically to get information regarding the CPU and pci devices.
To get an idea of the installed memory, use the `top` command which shows the current usage of the system processor and memory along with the `task id` of each `process` using the resources.

Also, the `htop` and `glances` commands are really nice, but you might have to install them through apt-get.